# Should i use belongsTo or hasOne in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Consider two models `A` and `B`

`A` -> relatedTo `B` is a `one to one` relationship

What is the difference in using (A ->`hasOne`-- B) and (A ->`belongsTo`-- B)?

Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

No, the difference depends on where your foreign key is.

In your example, if `A` has a `b_id` column, then `A` `belongsTo` `B`.

If `B` has an `a_id` column, then `A` `hasOne` or `hasMany` `B` depending on how many `B` should have.

Comment: Thank you. You're the only one to explain it in terms of where the keys are. Everyone else tries to explain it in "english" but sometimes your models are just too abstract for that to even make sense.

Comment: Couldn't `B` also `BelongTo`  `A`?

Comment: Let's say that `A` has `b_id` column. In this case, I can use `A.belongsTo(b)` or `B.hasOne(A)`. In both cases, ORM will add `b_id` to the `A` table. So, what's the difference here? Would you please explain?

Comment: Those two relationships are just the inverse of each other.  You are right they are basically the same thing.  However setting up both is useful if you need to query for `B` but all you have is the id for an `A`, then you would need to do something like `A::find($id)->B` which would use that `A.belongsTo(b)` relationship.  

On the inverse, if you need to query for an `A` but all you had is the id for a `B`, then you'd need the `B.hasOne(A)` relationship `B::find($id)->A`.

Comment: doesn't this logic kind of break for a many-to-many relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: The question was specifically about the difference between hasOne and belongsTo.

Comment: @user1669496, `A::find($id)->B` - what do you mean by `B` here - any method defined on `A` ?

Comment: This HasOne and BelongsTo is so confusing... if A have b_id i can use BelongsTo B... but i also can use HasOne in B pointing to A... when should i use one or another? or should i use both?

Comment: @DiegoVinícius ask yourself, does A owns B? Then A hasOne B. Does A belongs to B? Then A belongsTo B. It's a question of logic and language. Like User hasOne Account. But Post BELONGS TO its Author, not Post has one Author. Post does not have Author, it belongs to Author.

Answer (score 115):

Main difference is as below:

`belongsTo` and `belongsToMany` - you're telling Laravel that this table holds the foreign key that connects it to the other table.

`hasOne` and `hasMany` - you're telling Laravel that this table does not have the foreign key.

Comment: I think your answer is more simpler and understandable. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct. A `belongstoMany` (many-to-many) relationship doesn't keep the key on the table itself, but on the pivot table.

Comment: Great answer, this helps to understand the logic behind the function names.

Answer (score 4):

This is not about where the foreign key is.

The OP brought up 2 scenarios: A `hasOne` B, A `belongsTo` B

For a contextual example, let A = user and B = company.

> You can say "user owns(`hasOne`) a company" and conversely you can say "user worksAt(`belongsTo`) a company".

> In both scenarios, `user` has a `company_id` field

Please let that sink in for a moment. Thus, discussing the location of foreign key is a non starter. The most apt answer can be found here:
https://laravel.io/forum/04-20-2015-belongsto-vs-hasone

> although it works, it is an incorrect description of the relationship.

To answer the OP's question: **No, you should not use them interchangeably**.

They are usually used in pairs

1. A `belongsTo` B, B `hasMany` A
2. B `belongsTo` A, A `hasMany` B
3. A `hasOne` B, B `hasMany` A <- this will cause problems with both sides using `hasXXX`, see link.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between `hasOne` and `belongsTo` is where the foreign key column is located.

Let's say you have two entities: **User** and an **Account**.

If the `users` table has the `account_id` column then a **User** `belongsTo` **Account**. (And the **Account** either `hasOne` or `hasMany` **Users**)

But if the `users` table does not have the `account_id` column, and instead the `accounts` table has the `user_id` column, then **User** `hasOne` or `hasMany` **Accounts**.

Answer (score 0):

"BelongsTo" goes in the table with the "xxx_id" column.
Example:
A Country has Cities.
A City belongsTo a Country (country_id in cities table).
Another Example:
A Face hasOne Nose.
A Nose belongsTo a face (face_id in noses table).

Answer (score -1):

The model who's table contains the foreign key will have belongsTo() in it while the model who's table contains that primary key to which that foreign key is referencing to will have hasOne()... its easy the model that has the foreign key will have belongsTo() and the one that doesn't contain the foreign Key in that relationship will have hasOne(). and no they are not interchangeable using the wrong method will always return null as a result.