# HasOne relation with local storage return null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a model :

```
class Group extends Property {

    use HasFactory;
    protected $appends = ['logo', 'favicon'];
    protected $hidden = ['image', 'faviconImage'];
    public function getLogoAttribute()
    {
        return $this->image->url ?? null;
    }

    public function getFaviconAttribute()
    {
        return $this->faviconImage->url ?? null;
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(GroupImage::class, 'group_id');
    }

    public function faviconImage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(GroupImage::class, 'group_id');
    }
```

GroupImage structure

[image]

When I tried to call logo in my ressource : `$this->logo` I get null, even if I have data in my `group_images` table. I should somehow get data based on localKey ?

Comment: `->hasOne(Related::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`  is `logo` in your declaration the local key (usually `id`)  present in the table `groups` ? Or are you trying to do something else ? maybe add your table**S** structure to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between BelongsTo And HasOne in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582848/what-is-the-difference-between-belongsto-and-hasone-in-laravel)

Comment: @N69S I added the table structure of `GroupImages` but on `Group` I don't have the the logo_id or favicon_id

Comment: @N69S is possible to do something like that ?

Comment: @klsdskldsd i explicitly made the S in tables bold and capital  7 hours ago. what field are you trying to retrieve and depending on what value/fields ?