# How to get all data from two related tables in Laravel [one to many]

Tags: php, laravel

I am pretty new in Laravel and need write a simple backend API.
I am doing smething wrong and I dont know what, because I get some of data from Suppliers table and empty array **payments:[ ]**.

I am trying to get all data from two related tables - PAYMENTS and SUPPLIERS.
It`s a one to many relation SUPPLIERS_ID in PAYMENTS table is connected with ID in SUPPLIERS. Here I give You a graphic representation:

[image: a busy cat]

Here`s my code:

**Suppliers.php model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Suppliers extends Model
{
   public function payments()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Payments'); 
   }
}
```

**Payments.php model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Payments extends Model
{
   public function suppliers()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Suppliers'); 
  }
}
```

**PaymentsController.php**

```
use App\Payments;
use App\Suppliers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class PaymentsController extends Controller
{

public function index()
   {    
      $payments = Suppliers::with('payments')->get();
      return response($payments, Response::HTTP_OK);
   }
}
```

And i get the following answear:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Ekonaft","adress":"33-100 Tarnow ","email":"ekonaft@gmail.com","payments":[]}, 
{"id":2,"name":"Orlen","adress":"Ares testowy","email":"email@email.pl","payments":[]}]
```

What I`m doing wrong that I get te empty array **payments:[ ]** on the end of each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the inverse relationship on payments

```
belongsTo = has a foreign key to another table
```

Quoting an example

> [Should i use belongsTo or hasOne in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058949/should-i-use-belongsto-or-hasone-in-laravel)

This is how you can access suppliers from Payments

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Payments extends Model
{
   public function suppliers()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Suppliers'); 
  }
}
```

This is payments from suppliers

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Suppliers extends Model
{
   public function payments()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Payments','suppliers_ID','id'); 
   }
}
```

Also, make sure the id's are visible on the output (if id's are hidden, laravel can't work with the relationship). You can also specify the keys on the relationship if you want to use `hasOne`

Edit: add the keys names within the relation, your fk naming is in capslock

Answer (score 0):

Change you relations like bel

**Suppliers.php model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Suppliers extends Model
{
   public function payments()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(App\Payments::class, 'suppliers_ID', 'id'); 
   }
}
```

**Payments.php model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Payments extends Model
{
   public function suppliers()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(App\Suppliers::class, 'suppliers_ID', 'id'); 
  }
}
```

then try again..... :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty array of **payments:[]** due to miss-matching table relationship key name.

```
Please, make few changes in both relational function.

public function payments() 
{

    //return $this->hasMany('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    return $this->hasMany('App\Payments', 'suppliers_id'); 

}

public function suppliers()
{

    //return $this->belongsTo('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Suppliers', 'suppliers_id'); 

}
```

You can learn more about eloquent relationship directly from Laravel documentation for better understanding. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Let me know if you still getting same error.

Comment: Now, it works fine. Thanks a lot. But can you help me modify my qurey? I want to achive a little diffrent result. Now I have all records from SUPPLIERS and from PAYMENTS. How I can read all records from PAYMENTS and get  supplier name instead SUPPLIERS_ID.

Comment: You query will be like to get one suppliers who has at-least one payment:

$payments = Suppliers::whereHas('payments')->with('payments')->get();

Comment: To read all records from PAYMENTS and get supplier name instead SUPPLIERS_ID, you can use reverse relation.

$payments = Payments::with('suppliers')->get();

Comment: Thanks a lot! You save my evening.

Comment: Welcome @obaram