# Laravel One To One Relationship With Custom Foreign Key NOT WORKING

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-one, laravel-10, laravel-relations

I'm working with Laravel v10 and I have a `users` table and each user has also another record at the `members` table.

So in order to set up the One To One Relationship between these two Models:

**User Model**:

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Member::class, 'mbr_usr_id', 'id');
}
```

**Member Model**:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'mbr_usr_id');
}
```

Then I tried **`dd(auth()->user()->member->mbr_name);`** but didn't return any result and showed `null`!

However there is already a record at the `members` table with `mbr_usr_id` connected with `id` of `users` table.

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

---

This is the Migration of `users` table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->string('usr_name');
      ...
 });
```

And this is the Migration of `members` table:

```
Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('mbr_usr_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('mbr_usr_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');
});
```

Comment: Typo? its `mbr_fname` not `mbr_name`,

Comment: Please check your relationship again using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058949/should-i-use-belongsto-or-hasone-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can change foreign key and owner key in the `belongsTo()` method. In your case 'id' and 'mbr_usr_id'. This should work:

```
/**
 * Get the post that owns the comment.
 */
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
}
```

You can read about it more at
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Answer (score 0):

try this `dd(auth()->user->member)`

`->user()` and `->member()` return `Builder` object, while `->user` and `->member` return `User` and `Member` model instances.

Comment: auth()->user() returns current logged in User model, it **doesn't own** a property *user*

Comment: @Pippo yep, agree, my bad. But for `member()` it's still relevant.